# Vectorising this calculation instead of for loops

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy, vectorization

Is there a vectorised solution to replace the loop below? It takes around 5 minutes for the loop calculation, whereas the vectorised calculation would take seconds.

Note that the calculation could be anything (based on 2 lists of length 31).

```
#ICEBAL is a PY file
from ICEBAL import get_EdF
```

Here is the calculation below:

```
actls = [20.00,21.00,22.00,23.00,24.00,25.00,26.00,27.00,28.00,29.00,30.00,31.00,32.00,33.00,34.00,35.00,36.00,37.00,38.00,39.00,40.00,41.00,42.00,43.00,44.00,45.00,46.00,47.00,48.00,49.00,50.00]
preds = [19.00,20.00,21.00,22.00,23.00,24.00,25.00,26.00,27.00,28.00,29.00,30.00,31.00,32.00,33.00,34.00,35.00,36.00,37.00,38.00,39.00,40.00,41.00,42.00,43.00,44.00,45.00,46.00,47.00,48.00,49.00]
EdF = get_EdF(actls,preds)
```

I want to apply the EdF calculation to a test set. The loop below works, but is too slow to run.

```
test['EdF'] = 0
for i in range(0,884):
    test['EdF'].iloc[i] = get_EdF(np.squeeze(actuals[i:i+1]).tolist(),np.squeeze(predictionsneuralnet[i:i+1]).tolist()))
```

`test` is a standard Pandas dataset (with 884 rows).

```
print(np.array(actuals).shape)
print(np.array(predictionsneuralnet).shape)
```

Output is (884, 31) for both.

Comment: Please provide the `get_ICEBAL` and the `get_EdF` function definitions.

Comment: It is not relevant to explain how the calculation is derived - the calculation could be anything based on 2 lists of length 31. My question is essentially a general one.

Comment: Depending on what happens in these functions, they might or might not be vectorizable using numpy. In any case, questions here should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are `actuals` and `predictionsneuralnet` the same as `actls` and `preds`?

Comment: No they are not the same. ```actls``` and ```preds``` are 1 dimensional lists. ```actuals``` and ```predictionsneuralnet```are lists but in 884 "dimensions".```actuals[i]``` for any ```i``` is a 1D list though.

Comment: it's hard to replicate without some more data but maybe you could try a list comprehension, since you're iterating through the lists one element at a time (`l[i:i+1]` is the same as `l[i]`) so perhaps: `test['EdF'] = [getEdF(ac, pr) for ac, pred in zip(actuals, predictionsneuralnet)]`

Comment: Vectorization is not the only way to speed things up. Have you tried multi-threading ?

Comment: @josemz, that works. Thanks very much.